# MySQL search range and calculate difference

Tags: mysql, linux

This is an example, table PM0:

```
ID  DATA                V   A       W   PF      HZ  WH      S
1   2016-05-06 08:48:44 228 0.10    19  0.63    50  34020   1
1   2016-05-06 08:48:44 228 0.10    19  0.63    50  34020   1
2   2016-05-06 08:48:47 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34021   1
3   2016-05-06 08:48:49 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34023   1
4   2016-05-06 08:48:51 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34024   1
5   2016-05-06 08:48:53 228 0.10    19  0.63    50  34026   1
6   2016-05-06 08:48:56 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34027   1
7   2016-05-06 08:48:58 226 1.50    222 0.67    50  34030   1
8   2016-05-06 08:49:00 225 2.30    519 1.00    50  34040   1
9   2016-05-06 08:49:02 225 2.30    517 1.00    50  34050   1
10  2016-05-06 08:49:04 225 2.30    515 1.00    50  34070   1
11  2016-05-06 08:49:07 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34080   1
12  2016-05-06 08:49:09 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34090   1
13  2016-05-06 08:49:11 225 2.30    513 1.00    50  34100   1
14  2016-05-06 08:49:13 230 0.10    20  0.62    50  34105   0
15  2016-05-06 08:49:15 230 0.10    20  0.62    50  34106   0
16  2016-05-06 08:49:18 227 0.10    19  0.63    50  34107   0
17  2016-05-06 08:49:20 230 0.10    20  0.62    50  34108   0
18  2016-05-06 08:49:22 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34109   0
19  2016-05-06 08:49:24 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34110   0
20  2016-05-06 08:49:26 230 0.90    90  0.45    50  34115   0
21  2016-05-06 08:49:29 225 2.30    515 1.00    50  34120   0
22  2016-05-06 08:49:31 225 2.30    515 1.00    50  34130   0
23  2016-05-06 08:49:33 225 2.30    515 1.00    50  34140   0
24  2016-05-06 08:49:35 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34150   0
25  2016-05-06 08:49:37 225 2.30    513 1.00    50  34160   0
26  2016-05-06 08:49:40 230 0.10    20  0.61    50  34165   1
27  2016-05-06 08:49:42 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34166   1
28  2016-05-06 08:49:44 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34167   1
29  2016-05-06 08:49:46 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34168   1
30  2016-05-06 08:49:48 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34169   1
31  2016-05-06 08:49:51 226 0.10    19  0.63    50  34170   1
32  2016-05-06 08:49:53 225 2.10    456 0.94    50  34175   1
33  2016-05-06 08:49:55 225 2.30    517 1.00    50  34185   1
34  2016-05-06 08:49:57 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34195   1
35  2016-05-06 08:50:00 225 2.30    513 1.00    50  34200   1
36  2016-05-06 08:50:02 225 2.30    513 1.00    50  34210   1
37  2016-05-06 08:50:04 229 1.10    139 0.54    50  34215   1
38  2016-05-06 08:50:06 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34220   1
39  2016-05-06 08:50:08 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34221   1
40  2016-05-06 08:50:11 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34222   1
41  2016-05-06 08:50:13 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34223   1
42  2016-05-06 08:50:15 231 0.10    20  0.61    50  34224   1
43  2016-05-06 08:50:17 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34225   1
44  2016-05-06 08:50:19 225 2.30    519 1.00    50  34230   0
45  2016-05-06 08:50:22 225 2.30    516 1.00    50  34240   0
46  2016-05-06 08:50:24 225 2.30    515 1.00    50  34250   0
47  2016-05-06 08:50:26 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34260   0
48  2016-05-06 08:50:28 228 1.60    262 0.72    50  34265   0
49  2016-05-06 08:50:30 231 0.10    20  0.61    50  34266   0
50  2016-05-06 08:50:33 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34267   0
```

My problem:
SELECT * FROM PM0 WHERE S=1

```
ID  DATA                V   A       W   PF      HZ  WH      S
1   2016-05-06 08:48:44 228 0.10    19  0.63    50  34020   1
2   2016-05-06 08:48:47 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34021   1
3   2016-05-06 08:48:49 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34023   1
4   2016-05-06 08:48:51 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34024   1
5   2016-05-06 08:48:53 228 0.10    19  0.63    50  34026   1
6   2016-05-06 08:48:56 228 0.10    19  0.64    50  34027   1
7   2016-05-06 08:48:58 226 1.50    222 0.67    50  34030   1
8   2016-05-06 08:49:00 225 2.30    519 1.00    50  34040   1
9   2016-05-06 08:49:02 225 2.30    517 1.00    50  34050   1
10  2016-05-06 08:49:04 225 2.30    515 1.00    50  34070   1
11  2016-05-06 08:49:07 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34080   1
12  2016-05-06 08:49:09 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34090   1
13  2016-05-06 08:49:11 225 2.30    513 1.00    50  34100   1
26  2016-05-06 08:49:40 230 0.10    20  0.61    50  34165   1
27  2016-05-06 08:49:42 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34166   1
28  2016-05-06 08:49:44 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34167   1
29  2016-05-06 08:49:46 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34168   1
30  2016-05-06 08:49:48 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34169   1
31  2016-05-06 08:49:51 226 0.10    19  0.63    50  34170   1
32  2016-05-06 08:49:53 225 2.10    456 0.94    50  34175   1
33  2016-05-06 08:49:55 225 2.30    517 1.00    50  34185   1
34  2016-05-06 08:49:57 225 2.30    514 1.00    50  34195   1
35  2016-05-06 08:50:00 225 2.30    513 1.00    50  34200   1
36  2016-05-06 08:50:02 225 2.30    513 1.00    50  34210   1
37  2016-05-06 08:50:04 229 1.10    139 0.54    50  34215   1
38  2016-05-06 08:50:06 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34220   1
39  2016-05-06 08:50:08 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34221   1
40  2016-05-06 08:50:11 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34222   1
41  2016-05-06 08:50:13 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34223   1
42  2016-05-06 08:50:15 231 0.10    20  0.61    50  34224   1
43  2016-05-06 08:50:17 231 0.10    20  0.62    50  34225   1
```

Now, from ID 1 to 13 are sequential, I need difference between WH from 1 34020 and 13 34100, so 34100-34020=80, from ID 26 to 43, 34225-34165=60 and total 80+60=140.
140 result for S=1.
For S=0, from ID 14-25 -> 34160-34105=55 and ID 44-50 -> 34267-34230=37. 55+37=92.
92 result for S=0.

Please, I go crazy -_-

Comment: What do you want actually? Give us your expected result pls.

Comment: S is 1 or 0. Need sum of last result of any range - first result of any range, for 1 and for 0

Comment: Base on your sample data, you can post your expected result in your question.

Comment: Now, from ID 1 to 13 are sequential, I need difference between WH from 1 34020 and 13 34100, so 34100-34020=80, from ID 26 to 43, 34225-34165=60 and total 80+60=140. 140 result for S=1. For S=0, from ID 14-25 -> 34160-34105=55 and ID 44-50 -> 34267-34230=37. 55+37=92 result for S=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think @Quicker's answer is right if you check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dc4a/1/0).

And this will help you;)

```
select
    t1.s, sum(t2.wh - t1.wh) as diff
from pm0 t1
left join pm0 t2 on t1.id + 1 = t2.id and t1.s = t2.s and t2.data = date(now())
where t1.data = date(now())
group by t1.s
order by t1.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dc4a/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE PM0
    (`ID` int, `DATA` datetime, `V` int, `A` int, `W` int, `PF` numeric, `HZ` int, `WH` int, `S` int)
;

INSERT INTO PM0
    (`ID`, `DATA`, `V`, `A`, `W`, `PF`, `HZ`, `WH`, `S`)
VALUES
    (1, '2016-05-06 08:48:44', 228, 0.10, 19, 0.63, 50, 34020, 1),
    (2, '2016-05-06 08:48:47', 228, 0.10, 19, 0.64, 50, 34021, 1),
    (3, '2016-05-06 08:48:49', 228, 0.10, 19, 0.64, 50, 34023, 1),
    (4, '2016-05-06 08:48:51', 228, 0.10, 19, 0.64, 50, 34024, 1),
    (5, '2016-05-06 08:48:53', 228, 0.10, 19, 0.63, 50, 34026, 1),
    (6, '2016-05-06 08:48:56', 228, 0.10, 19, 0.64, 50, 34027, 1),
    (7, '2016-05-06 08:48:58', 226, 1.50, 222, 0.67, 50, 34030, 1),
    (8, '2016-05-06 08:49:00', 225, 2.30, 519, 1.00, 50, 34040, 1),
    (9, '2016-05-06 08:49:02', 225, 2.30, 517, 1.00, 50, 34050, 1),
    (10, '2016-05-06 08:49:04', 225, 2.30, 515, 1.00, 50, 34070, 1),
    (11, '2016-05-06 08:49:07', 225, 2.30, 514, 1.00, 50, 34080, 1),
    (12, '2016-05-06 08:49:09', 225, 2.30, 514, 1.00, 50, 34090, 1),
    (13, '2016-05-06 08:49:11', 225, 2.30, 513, 1.00, 50, 34100, 1),
    (14, '2016-05-06 08:49:13', 230, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34105, 0),
    (15, '2016-05-06 08:49:15', 230, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34106, 0),
    (16, '2016-05-06 08:49:18', 227, 0.10, 19, 0.63, 50, 34107, 0),
    (17, '2016-05-06 08:49:20', 230, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34108, 0),
    (18, '2016-05-06 08:49:22', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34109, 0),
    (19, '2016-05-06 08:49:24', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34110, 0),
    (20, '2016-05-06 08:49:26', 230, 0.90, 90, 0.45, 50, 34115, 0),
    (21, '2016-05-06 08:49:29', 225, 2.30, 515, 1.00, 50, 34120, 0),
    (22, '2016-05-06 08:49:31', 225, 2.30, 515, 1.00, 50, 34130, 0),
    (23, '2016-05-06 08:49:33', 225, 2.30, 515, 1.00, 50, 34140, 0),
    (24, '2016-05-06 08:49:35', 225, 2.30, 514, 1.00, 50, 34150, 0),
    (25, '2016-05-06 08:49:37', 225, 2.30, 513, 1.00, 50, 34160, 0),
    (26, '2016-05-06 08:49:40', 230, 0.10, 20, 0.61, 50, 34165, 1),
    (27, '2016-05-06 08:49:42', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34166, 1),
    (28, '2016-05-06 08:49:44', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34167, 1),
    (29, '2016-05-06 08:49:46', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34168, 1),
    (30, '2016-05-06 08:49:48', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34169, 1),
    (31, '2016-05-06 08:49:51', 226, 0.10, 19, 0.63, 50, 34170, 1),
    (32, '2016-05-06 08:49:53', 225, 2.10, 456, 0.94, 50, 34175, 1),
    (33, '2016-05-06 08:49:55', 225, 2.30, 517, 1.00, 50, 34185, 1),
    (34, '2016-05-06 08:49:57', 225, 2.30, 514, 1.00, 50, 34195, 1),
    (35, '2016-05-06 08:50:00', 225, 2.30, 513, 1.00, 50, 34200, 1),
    (36, '2016-05-06 08:50:02', 225, 2.30, 513, 1.00, 50, 34210, 1),
    (37, '2016-05-06 08:50:04', 229, 1.10, 139, 0.54, 50, 34215, 1),
    (38, '2016-05-06 08:50:06', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34220, 1),
    (39, '2016-05-06 08:50:08', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34221, 1),
    (40, '2016-05-06 08:50:11', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34222, 1),
    (41, '2016-05-06 08:50:13', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34223, 1),
    (42, '2016-05-06 08:50:15', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.61, 50, 34224, 1),
    (43, '2016-05-06 08:50:17', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34225, 1),
    (44, '2016-05-06 08:50:19', 225, 2.30, 519, 1.00, 50, 34230, 0),
    (45, '2016-05-06 08:50:22', 225, 2.30, 516, 1.00, 50, 34240, 0),
    (46, '2016-05-06 08:50:24', 225, 2.30, 515, 1.00, 50, 34250, 0),
    (47, '2016-05-06 08:50:26', 225, 2.30, 514, 1.00, 50, 34260, 0),
    (48, '2016-05-06 08:50:28', 228, 1.60, 262, 0.72, 50, 34265, 0),
    (49, '2016-05-06 08:50:30', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.61, 50, 34266, 0),
    (50, '2016-05-06 08:50:33', 231, 0.10, 20, 0.62, 50, 34267, 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
 t1.s, sum(t2.wh - t1.wh) as diff
from pm0 t1
left join pm0 t2 on t1.id + 1 = t2.id and t1.s = t2.s
group by t1.s
order by t1.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dc4a/5/0)**:

```
| S | diff |
|---|------|
| 1 |  140 |
| 0 |   92 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I try your query!

Comment: Hi Mippy, where I can insert WHERE DATA = DATE(NOW()) for filter today rows?

Comment: @eliafino Add a `where` clause, and add this condition on left join. pls check my answer .

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is this:

SELECT s,max(wh)-min(wh) FROM PM0 group by S

Do not forget to put an index on S.

Comment: Check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dc4a/1/0), seems to be not right result. 162 for s=0, 205 for s=1...